# Changing WordPress dropdown menu to click instead of hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to **change the WordPress menu dropdown to onclick instead of hover**; I want to see the menu when an item is clicked, but WordPress does it on hover.

Here is the code of **what I have attempted so far**, but it doesn't work.

##### Jquery:

```
$(".header_menu_res ul li").live("click",function() {
    if($(this).find(".adv_categories").length==1) {
        if($(this).find(".adv_categories").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find(".adv_categories").removeClass('importantRule');
            $(this).parent("ul").find(".sub-menu").removeClass('importantRule');
        } else {
            $(this).find(".adv_categories").addClass('importantRule');
        }
    } 
});
```

##### HTML:

```
<div class="header_menu_res">
<ul id="menu-header"><li class="menu-item"><a class="primary" href="http://localhost/?page_id=7">Categories</a>
<div class="adv_categories" id="adv_categories"><ul class="maincat-list"><li class="maincat cat-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/?ad_cat=acs-consultants" title="">ACS Consultants</a>  </li>
<li class="maincat cat-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/?ad_cat=business-development" title="">Business Development</a> </li></ul>
</div></li></ul>
</div>
```

##### CSS:

```
.importantRule { display:block !important; }
```

Anytime I click `Categories`, the page is scrolled to the top?

Comment: the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: I changed to `.on()` and still same result.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kkpLhzqj/1/

See my fiddle. It's really easy actually:

```
 $(".header_menu_res ul > .menu-item").click(function() {
    $('.maincat-list').toggle("slow");
 });
```

Old version of jsfiddle did not work with multiple dropdowns, this one does:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkpLhzqj/2/

Comment: thanks for this but how do i cancel the hover that default with wordpress.  When i leave the sub menu it disappears when it should remain.

Comment: That's probably done with CSS, so if you remove the CSS from the CSS file inside wordpress, it will not happen again. (be sure to make a back-up of the CSS file)!!

Comment: I've tried this on my file, i deleted the li:hover on the style.css, could it be jQuery of the theme i'm using?

Comment: yes it could be also jquery that is responsible for the `:hover` effect, that's something you have to figure out. Or give me a link to the site so i can take a look.